# Python if wrong answer

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, if-statement

```
temp = '32'
if temp > 85:
      print "Hot"
elif temp > 62:
      print "Comfortable" 
else:
      print "Cold"
```

Why does it give output 'Hot' , shouldn't it be 'Cold' ?

Answer (score 6):

Because `temp` is a string and not an integer.

For Benji: we know it's a string because the value assigned to the variable is wrapped in single quotes!

More for Benji: we know it's not an integer because if it was, it would be quote-less! `temp = 34` like so

Comment: Best answer in the world, truly inspirational.

Comment: Can you please explain how we know `temp` is a string?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! How do we know it's not an integer though?

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, you are comparing a string to an integer, and should really just compare integers to one another. The reason why it returns `True` however, is because :

```
>>> type('32')  
<type 'str'>
>>> type(85)
<type 'int'>
>>> 'str' > 'int 
True
```

If you were curious how different types are evaluated in Python 2.7 with `<`:

```
>>> """any number type""" < dict() < list() < set() < str() < tuple()
True
```

Note that as mentioned by [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) in the comments, number types are placed explicitly before all other types, and this behavior is not a result of the alphabetical sorting of type names.

Comment: `'str' > 'int'` is just a coincidence here. Python explicitly puts numbers before other types, that has no connection to the alphabetical sorting order of their type names.

Answer (score 2):

By putting quotes around '32', you're defining it as a string, and then comparing it to an int.

Python evaluates strings to be  'greater than' ints, based on the type name: [How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)

Just remove the quotes around '32', and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string to an integer. Strings are always greater than integers regardless of their content. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int) for more on why this is the case. Just make your variable an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotations around the number temp I.e.

temp = 42

Not

temp = '42'

This is due to letters and number strings are coverted to their ASCII equivalent then compared. An example of this is the letter 'A' = 0, 'a' = 30. You can look these values up online for more understanding.